# How to open stream with composer/ any other library

Tags: php, composer-php, libraries, require

I've been trying to find the solution to my problem for DAYS. I couldn't find anyone to simply explain what to do to open stream with composer/any other library. It seems this is so simple, everyone knows how to do it.

my `index.php`

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

?>
```

error message:

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/(webhostusername)/(subdomain.mydomain)/index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/(webhostusername)/(subdomain.mydomain.com)/index.php on line 3

What else should I do? Do the composer files need to be in the same folder as my subdomain?

more information:

- using Dreamhost shared hosting
- installed composer via SSH
- I want to use a library (`raiym/instagram-php-scraper`)

Comment: I added some formatting to your question. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can format your questions nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to give a full path to the file you are trying to include.

`require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

But you most definitely are trying to include a file that doesn't exist. Is the index.php file in a different directory than the vendor directory?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I installed composer again in the right directory. I tried `code[require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';]  and `code`[require 'vendor/autoload.php';]  and I'm still getting the same error :/                   "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/(webhostusername)/(subdomain.mydomain.com)/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/(webhostusername)/(subdomain.mydomain.com)/index.php on line 3"

Comment: It is not that you have to reinstall composer in a different directory, you have to make sure that the `require` is pointing to the correct directory.
If you run `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` in your index.php, then it expects the vendor directory to be in the same place as the `index.php` file.

Comment: Can you list the contents of the directory where the `index.php` file is located?

Comment: oh i see, /home/(webhostusername)/(domain)

Comment: I was just now successful including the file in a project on my local server! `code`(require (__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');) worked like a charm. I don't know why but I still cant get it to work with my hosting service.

Comment: I looked up the directory for the file I want to include and the directory seems fine
[sshconnection]:~$ find -name "autoload.php"
./home/(username)/(domainfile)/vendor/autoload.php        (&)                                         
./vendor/autoload.php

Comment: And where exactly is the index.php located on your hosting service?

Comment: ./(subdomain.domain)/firstpage.php - I just renamed index.php

Comment: I realized what I did wrong with the web host. I installed composer according to the guide they had and didn't realize that i installed it in a different directory. I fixed the issue. Thank you!!!